# Show integer n exists such that $f_1(z) = f_2(z) + 2\pi ni$ where $f_1 , f_2$ are holomorphic and satisfy $e^{f(z)}=g(z)$ for some holomorphic $g(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

This portion is a secondary question following the proof for a certain theorem. The theorem states:

Let U $\subseteq$ C be simply connected region and g: U $\rightarrow$ C is holomorphic. Then, there exists a holomorphic function f s.t. $e^{f(z)} =g(z)$ for all z $\epsilon$ C.

I was able to prove this by considering $\frac{g'}{g}$.

I would now like to show that if there are two functions $f_1, f_2$ that satisfy the theorem, then there exists an integer $n$ s.t. $f_1(z)=f_2(z)+ 2\pi ni$. If g(z) is the same for both $f(z)$ then the proof is rather trivial but I don't think that's the case and i'm rather lost. Since this theorem is closely related to the branch of logarithms, I think that may be useful to get the $2\pi ni$ term but I'm not sure how.

Any help to steer me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{f_1(z)}=e^{f_2(z)}$ gives $f_1(z)-f_2(z) =2\pi ih(z)$ for some integer valued function $h$. [This is basic Trigonometry]. Since the left side of this equation is continuous so is the right side. The only continuous integer valued functions on $U$ are constant functions [This is by  connectedness of $U$]. This finishes the proof.

Comment: Does that mean $f_1(z), f_2(z)$ have the same $g(z)$? That was sort of my initial confusion. If so, thanks for the proof!

Comment: Yes, what you are asked to prove is if  a given holomorphic function  $g(z)$ can be written in the form $e^{f(z)}$ for two functions $f=f_1$ and $f=f_2$ then there exists an integer $n$ (independent of $z$) such that $f_1(z)=f_2(z)+2n \pi i$. @Meow